# why this error is coming i have not even started coding

Tags: java, android, api, google-app-engine

Multiple entries with same key: Google Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19) and Google Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: Google       Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19) and Google Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19)

```
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:150)
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableBiMap.<init>(RegularImmutableBiMap.java:77)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap$Builder.build(ImmutableBiMap.java:172)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.KeyValuePane.<init>(KeyValuePane.java:134)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.AndroidProjectConfigurable.<init>(AndroidProjectConfigurable.java:65)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.<init>(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:221)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.initializeInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:228)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter$1.compute(ServiceManagerImpl.java:216)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:884)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:207)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:37)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.getInstance(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:116)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.AndroidProjectSettingsService.openAndSelectDependenciesEditor(AndroidProjectSettingsService.java:129)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.EditLibraryAndDependenciesAction.doPerform(EditLibraryAndDependenciesAction.java:38)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AbstractProjectStructureAction.doPerform(AbstractProjectStructureAction.java:56)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.AndroidStudioGradleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidStudioGradleAction.java:65)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:312)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question...what are you trying to do?

Comment: i havent even started coding.. this error is popping up.

Comment: This is a bug in android studio 1.4. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189002&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: @Raghavendra it figured it out. Android studio was was telling me to delete one of the similar files installed in api level 19(arm system image in my case) as soon as i deleted one of the two it started working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed by deleting and reinstalling SDK Platform 19 with the SDK Manager.

This worked for me as well (Android Studio 15 Preview)

please look
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189002&q=label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars