# Android Studio -> Project Structure not working

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

Android Studio gives error in log when I try to open Project Structure.

Here's log

```
IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: Google 
Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19) and Google 
Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19)`
```

Version

- Android Studio 2.0 Preview

Comment: Have a look at this [StackoverFlow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201479/why-this-error-is-coming-i-have-not-even-started-coding)

Comment: Delete & Install worked.. Thanks btw